# practical connection of LED to a MCU

Tags: 8051

[image]

While aiming to blink an led with this 8051 MCU, I used configuration 1 to connect my LED. It doesn't work. But 2 and 3 worked. logically, there should not be any reason behind why configuration 1 do not works. Because it will alternatively give 5V (assuming no tolerance) and 0 V. But I'm guessing it didn't work because although the pin is switching between 5 V and 0, the MCU is not able to supply sufficient current to the LED, because the MCU is current limited. Is this correct guess? or any other reason behind it?

Comment: Even if the MCU is current-limited, it is usually able to supply enough power to drive a LED. It could be a bit faint, but still visibly on. I rather assume that you made an error when setting up configuration 1 (i.e LED connected the wrong way round)

Comment: What does the datasheet say about current out of the pin? Tbh it looks like you connected LED to the wrong pin in the first example or something of that sort (or maybe not). In the first case you need to supply ~(5V-2V)/220Ohm ~ 14mA. But at the same time example 2 works, where it needs to sink exactly the same current. Look for bad connection. Check if voltages change on resistor/LED. Check pin, software.

Comment: please note, its a simulation, not in work bench. the configuration I'm talking about is not working in the SIMULATION .

Comment: @PMF sorry but what is wrong in that? are you saying the configuring showing in the picture is RIGHT but I messed it up while doing practical connection?

Comment: @Sayan if you do blink, then cases 1 and 2 are pretty much identical. Probe voltages on every side of the resistor for case 1. Tbh I'm inclined to believe you connected to the wrong pin or something of that sort. As dumb as it sounds, we've all been there.

Comment: @Ilya are the really identical? isn't it that in case 2 we can draw much more current because of the 5V external supply?

Comment: @Sayan if they blink, it's 100% identical. Where do you think MCU takes current for LED from in 1? From the very same supply. It just goes through MCU first. And in 2 in goes through the same MCU into ground.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/132130/discussion-between-ilya-and-sayan).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, your guess is correct. The 8051 has a peculiar I/O structure, sometimes referred to as "quasi-tristate" or "quasi-bidirectional". The output drivers can pull down strongly, but there is only a *very* weak internal pullup resistance that is permanently connected. In order to improve the risetime when switching high, a pullup transistor in parallel with that resistance is switched on for a very brief time — 1 µs or less — too short for you to see it on your LED.

Answer (score 0):

The 8051 as it was originally designed could only actively pull down on its gpio. There was an inbuilt pullup resistor. As for the reasoning behind that design decision at Intel, I have no idea, but clearly it didn’t affect the popularity of the architecture. Time to read the datasheet carefully so there’s no more surprises.

#1 would be feeding be led via something like a 50k resistance of the internal pullup, so you might get a small glow.

#2 has the best chance of actually working although as others have mentioned the sink current was not that great by today’s standards.

#3 just works as the internal pullup is enough to bias the transistor on.

Using a pnp transistor with a base resistor would be a better choice for driving an led.

There are variants of the 8051 that have ‘normal’ gpio with the direction register to set input/output and totem pole drivers like some of the offerings from Silabs

Comment: *"reasoning behind that design decision"* -- it eliminated the need for separate "output enable" registers, which is how most other microcontrollers handle it.