# LED wired to GPIO in an unconventional way

Tags: microcontroller, led, current, gpio, pins

I was looking at a schematic for an existing board, and I was surprised to see that this LED was wired up to a GPIO pin (LED1 label), but as if the current was gonna go to ground "inside" the microcontroller via the pin (see the image below).

Usually, what I expect of an LED is to be wired up to a pin the other way, where we use the pin as an output that we set High when we want to power the LED, and then the current flows via the LED to a ground symbol on the schematic.

Here, the only way I can imagine of getting the LED to light up is to set the pin as an input and enable its internal pulldown resistor, which provides a path to ground for the current that travels from the 3.3V source and through the LED/resistor, and putting the GPIO pin in a high impedance state if we want to turn off the LED, but all of this seems a bit dumb to me.

Can someone explain to me how this configuration works ?

[image]

Comment: Your intuition is correct. The current flows into the GPIO pin and down to ground inside the micro controller. When the GPIO is configured as an output and driven low, the LED will be on. You can turn off the LED either by configuring the GPIO as an input, or by configuring it as a push-pull output driven high, or by configuring it as an open-drain output driven high.

Comment: this is pretty common, parts used to be able to sink more than they could source, and you would see this.  These days you will see it either way, depends on the engineer.

Comment: such as https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/598266/practical-connection-of-led-to-a-mcu/598277#598277 this configuration is better suited for this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This configuration will work provided the turn-on voltage of the LED is less than the 3.3 V supply minus Vout of the GPIO pin when the output is low. This will probably work fine with red or IR LEDs, but it may not work with blue, white or UV LEDs, because their forward voltage drop when on may be too large. Such a configuration used to be quite common in the TTL days, when Vcc was 5.0V.

It works just as you suspect. Conventional current flows from the 3.3V supply, through the resistor and LED, and then through the (low) GPIO pin. Internally, it probably then flows through a MOSFET to ground.

Comment: Even a blue led will work. Even if at 3.6V @ 20mA nominal, just at lower current. 3.3V  with a 330ohm resistor will still be visible just not very bright.

Comment: This is a good answer, but there are white LED's available now that will very reliably turn on with a 3.3 V supply (and suitable current limiting resistor). But the caution to double-check the Vf is still valid and useful and helpful.

Answer (score 7):

This is a perfectly acceptable and normal way to drive an LED.

You configure the GPIO pin as an output, and set it Low (logic 0) - the GPIO pin will then be connected to ground by the microcontroller, turning on the LED.

Setting the pin to a High (logic 1) will connect the pin to Vcc to turn off the LED.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score 7):

This is probably the most common way to drive an LED from a CMOS or bipolar IC. The LED is 'on' when the output is driven 'low'. We can thank solid-state physics.

The reason is that N-channel MOSFETs are better than their complements, all other things being equal. The N-channel majority carriers (electrons) have a higher mobility than the P-channel majority carriers (holes).

So, for a transistor of a given size, you'll get lower Rds(on) with an N-channel than a P-channel transistor. That means less voltage drop across the transistor so it runs cooler and there is more voltage available for the LED.

Take, as an example, the [LAN91C111](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/00002276A.pdf). You'll notice that the two LED drive outputs from this chip are called nLEDA and nLEDB. The leading 'n' means that they are negated- they go low when the LED is active. Sure enough when we look up the [evaluation board schematic](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/91c111ref.pdf), we find this:

[image]

Answer (score 4):

A GPIO allows for general purpose input and output. When configured as an output the pin can actually be used for both input and output. That is, in other words, when used as a output the pin can sink current or source current. There is nothing to prevent the output from sinking current by going low. In fact this is a desirable function.

Your gpio is set to sink current from the LED. While some microcontrollers may be better suited to source current, many are able to sink without issue or difference. Some may even be better at sinking compared to sourcing. The only logical difference is an inverted logic for on/off. You set the gpio to low to turn the LED on and high or high-z/input to turn the LED off.

Comment: "The output can work for both input and output. That is, in other words, current sourcing or current sinking."

This makes it sound like sourcing is an output mode and sinking is an input mode. They are both output modes, just opposite polarities. To source current a transistor between the positive supply and the output is turned on, to sink current a transistor between ground and the output is turned on. To use the GPIO pin as an input the output transistors are both turned off and a separate circuit senses the voltage on the pin.

Comment: It's an analogy that I explained in the next sentence

Comment: It's an incorrect analogy, and I don't see anything in the second sentence that makes it any less confusing. The pin is being used as an output, it sinking or sourcing current has nothing to do with using it as an input.

Comment: @godjihyo ok... feel free to answer it yourself

Comment: I think the OP is confused by "output". The word "output" doesn't mean (as I believe they think it might) the direction of current, or of electrons, but that the device considers itself the boss, "in charge" of the voltage on the pin and is prepared to source or sink current to reach the voltage which it decides. Input instead means that the device does no asserting, instead carefully detecting the voltage on the pin, presumably set by some outside circuitry.

Comment: I agree that the first paragraph of this answer is confusing if not outright wrong. If a student believes that input and sinking are more or less the same thing, and that output and sourcing are more or less the same thing, then it seems like statements like "the output can work for both input and output" can only make their confusion worse. I think the paragraph would be much clearer if you added some more descriptive words, something like this: "A GPIO allows for general purpose *signal* input and *signal* output. The *signal* output can work for both *current* input and *current* output."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, your hypothesis about this circuit working is true. The conventional current flows from VCC down to the Resistor and LED and into the LED0 pin shown in picture. The maximum current that can flow through this LED and resistor configuration is 10mA and almost all of the microcontrollers can sink that much current without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

There's a good reason for this, which no other answer has covered. Many families of logic gates are not symmetrical - they can only source a milliampere or less of current, but can sink 10 mA or more. Most circuits therefore will always drive LEDs or other medium-power electronics active-low as general good practice, because the design will work with any logic family.

For microcontrollers, this is almost always the case - very few have symmetrical drive. So almost always, this is how you want your microcontroller to drive LEDs.

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly common and removes a some of the Vdd current in the microcontroller.

You configure the output in open drain mode where only the low side fet will be operated.

[image: https://os.mbed.com/teams/TVZ-Mechatronics-Team/wiki/Digital-inputs-and-outputs]

You can even run this with a power rail higher than Vdd, such as 5V, to allow leds with a higher forward voltage to work. Such as Blue, with 3.2 V.

Answer (score 0):

You can drive a LED (more precisely, a network of LED and resistor in series) in three possible ways:

1. **From the side of the anode (the cathode is grounded).** Then high input voltage will light up the LED. The current will exit the upper transistor of the output and go through the LED to ground.
2. **From the side of the cathode (the anode is connected to Vcc).** Then low input voltage will light up the LED. The current will exit Vcc, pass through the LED and enter the bottom transistor of the output.
3. **From both sides (both anode and cathode are connected to outputs like a bridge circuit).** Then only when there is high input voltage at the anode and low input voltage at the cathode, the LED will light up. The current will exit the upper transistor of the one output, go through the LED to and enter the bottom transistor of the other output. Simply speaking, the current will flow between the two outputs. This configuration was widely used in the so-called "dynamic LED indication".